# Is this a PHP Bug? Run foreach over mixed array with an if

Tags: php, foreach

I was implementing the piwik api and I found unexpected behavior on my local copy of piwik. (The latest piwik version does not contain this piece of code anymore.)

Here is the bug:

```
<?php
$arrtest = array('label' => array(1,2,3), 0 => 'zero');
foreach($arrtest as $key => $value) {
    if($key != 'label') {    
        var_dump($value);
    }
}
?>
```

The given code should print string(4) 'zero' after skipping the 'label' key. But it does not print anything. if I replace the inner code with:

```
if($key === 'label') continue;
var_dump($value);
```

Then it prints: string(4) "zero"

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: php bug or your code bug, what's more likely ?

Comment: Tens of millions of lines of PHP are chugging along, serving a tremendous percentage of the Internet's requests every day, and *most* of it is more complex than your example. What are the odds that your trivial loop has uncovered such a fundamental bug in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use strict comparison, always:

```
$key !== 'label'
```

With your original code `$key != 'label'`, when `0` is compared to `'label'`, `'label'` is actually *coerced into a int*, and because `label` does not start with a number, it is automatically coerced to `0`, the default value of an int. You're now comparing `0 != 0`, which of course is false.

Compare:

```
0 == 'label'; // true
0 === 'label'; // false
```

Comment: Wellll, perhaps not _always_, but you have to be really _really_ sure you want loose equals when you use it.

Comment: @Izkata I haven't encountered a circumstance where it would make sense to *not* use strict comparison operators; using loose comparison operators is just asking for subtle bugs to be introduced into your code.

Comment: More than 10 years of php coding and I had never run into this one! Great explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @mc10 One example: generic function that has to compare numbers from different sources.  Strict-equals says that, for example, `5` and `'5'` are different.  I've used it on rare occasion - it keeps code simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: @Izkata Numbers should be stored as numbers, regardless of the source. If they aren't, when you retrieve them, you should coerce them into `int`s or `double`s yourself before doing comparisons with them, to reduce the areas where you have to worry about differing types and minimize bugs.

Comment: I mentioned it before, it's also a good idea to remember that `0` and `1` can also be treated as `FALSE` and `TRUE`, respectively. So if `$x = 0` then `if( $x ) { echo "Will Never Echo, $x is FALSE"; }`

Comment: I think in those cases that it'd be better to explicitly check if it's equal to zero or not: `if ($x !== 0)`, for instance. You shouldn't for the most part use non-booleans for test conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This is PHPs "unusual" type coercion rules in effect. In the loop instance you're interested in, `$key` is 0. Thus the comparison is `if (0 != 'label')`, comparing an integer to a string. In this instance, it will coerce the string to an integer using its inbuilt rules. This converts `label` to `0`. So, `0 != 0` is the test, which fails.

As you've noticed, use type strict comparisons (which don't perform the type coercion), to avoid this.